# C# struct with an array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, xna

I am making a game using C# with the XNA framework. The player is a 2D soldier on screen and the user is able to fire bullets. The bullets are stored in an array. I have looked into using Lists and arrays for this and I came to the conclusion that an array is a lot better for me, as there will be a lot of bullets firing and being destroyed at once, something that I read Lists don't handle so well.

After reading through some posts on the XNA forums, this came to my attention:
http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/16037/84353.aspx

I have created a struct like so:

```
// Bullets
struct Bullet
{
    Vector2 Position;
    Vector2 Velocity;
    float Rotation;
    Rectangle BoundingRect;
    bool Active;
}
```

And I made the array like this:

```
Bullet[] bulletCollection = new Bullet[100];
```

But when I try to do some code like this:

```
    // Fire bullet
    if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bulletCollection.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!bulletCollection[i].Active)
            {
                // something
            }
        }
```

I get the following error:

> 'Zombie_Apocalypse.Game1.Bullet.Active'
>   is inaccessible due to its protection
>   level

Can anyone lend a hand? I have no idea why this error is popping up, or even if I'm declaring the array properly or anything... as the post on the XNA forums doesn't go into detail about that.

Thank you for any help you can provide. :)

Comment: Besides the problem you've had - you might want to consider not using arrays (or fixed-length-arrays). You might run into problems ie: fast gun, more then 100 bullets needed. Consider using object collections where objects (when no longer active) just destroy themselves.

Comment: @riffnl, actually no, using fixed buffers in XNA is almost always the best choice, because you want to reduce garbage collections as close as possible to zero, even zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe C# makes members private by default, so you'd simply need to make `Active` a public field:

```
public bool Active;
```

More advisable would be to make it a property with a public `get` accessor, keeping the `set` private:

```
public bool Active { get; private set; }
```

---

**Update** (for those arriving at this question just now):

Alternately, it may be a better idea (whether for better performance or to turn fewer heads among your game developer colleagues) to use a `readonly` field for this purpose:

```
public readonly bool Active;
```

In the latter case you would need to set the value of `Active` in your type's constructor.

I originally answered this question from the perspective of a non-game developer, and so this answer (like anything you read here or elsewhere on the internet) should be taken with a grain of salt. I maintain that using a property to hide the setter on a field—whether within a struct or a class—makes sense in typical applications. Comments that others have left lead me to believe that wrapping a field in a property is *not* the norm for games, however (due to understandable performance considerations); and so you can probably safely ignore my final suggestion.

Comment: Hah, that should have been obvious xD Thanks. Am I declaring my array correctly though? C# doesn't through any errors when compiling but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Also I have to wait 9 minutes before I accept your answer, but I will do when I can. :)

Comment: @Whitey: You are declaring your array correctly. Since `Bullet` is a struct, the array is filled with default values (just as an `int[]` would be filled with zeros); if you had made it a class, the array would be full of nulls and you would need to instantiate each bullet.

Comment: using properties on stucts is not a rule to be followed in XNA (even the class library doesn't use it) because of performance implications. Actually the rule is not to use properties unless encapsulation *is* needed, so you can eliminate redundant copying of data.

Comment: Is there any advantage whatsoever to wrapping struct fields with 'standard' properties?  If so, what?

Comment: @supercat: You mean aside from being able to declare a private setter? Or are you suggesting that there is no point in doing even that?

Comment: @DanTao: I meant using properties with public get and set, and for some reason missed the `private` in your example, though even that I would only consider worthwhile in cases where only selective combinations of values are allowed.  The main reason for making struct properties read-only was to make compilers squawk at `ReadOnlyStruct.SomeProperty = someValue`; since compilers would squawk just fine at `ReadOnlyStruct.SomeField = someValue;`, one could flag such constructs without having to wrap fields in a property.

Comment: @DanTao: A PODS is the optimal kind of storage location for small fixed collections of orthogonal values.  If a struct isn't going to enforce invariants on its fields, hiding the fields behind a property simply makes it less obvious that the struct simply represents a fixed collection of orthogonal values.

Comment: @supercat: I don't mean to argue with you on it. I personally am a fan of structs with public readonly fields rather than properties; I left the suggestion as what is, in my experience, the most idiomatic way of exposing fields in the .NET community. I also updated the question, though, with the disclaimer that I'm not a game developer and so don't know what's accepted in, e.g., the XNA world.

Comment: @supercat: With respect to the question specifically, my main intention was to point out to the OP that simply adding `public` to the field declaration (the direct answer to his question) would not be a good idea on its own as it would open up a new can of worms. So making the field readonly in some sense was really what I meant to recommend; the use of a property to do that was merely a means to that end. (Am now updating the answer again with a suggestion to use `readonly` instead.)

Comment: Some bad idioms have appeared in the early days of .net.  Some have gone by the wayside, but unfortunately some persist, including the idea that all types should encapsulate everything--even types that exist to be transparent data holders.  Wrapping struct-type fields in properties *or making them `readonly`* will impair performance, especially with large structs.  If doing such things will allow a struct to enforce some useful invariants, that benefit may be worth the cost.  OTOH, going out of one's way to incur those costs without first identifying a potential benefit seems crazy.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `public`

```
public struct Bullet
{
    public Vector2 Position;
    public Vector2 Velocity;
    public float Rotation;
    public Rectangle BoundingRect;
    pubilc bool Active;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# makes all class member private by default - you need to specify the access modifiers:

```
public struct Bullet
{
  public Vector2 Position;
  public Vector2 Velocity;
  public float Rotation;
  public Rectangle BoundingRect;
  public bool Active;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe making the `struct` itself public is all that's necessary, since struct fields default to `public` while class fields default to `private`. However, as others suggest, explicitly making your fields public is good practice: write what you mean, instead of letting the language assume for you! :)